# Convert the incoming data from serial port to interger

Tags: python, string, arduino, type-conversion, integer

I am trying to use my accelerometer as a mouse by using Arduino. The data from the serial port is in bytes and I want to convert it into integer so that I can use those values to simulate my mouse.

Here is my code:

```py
import serial
import pydirectinput

pydirectinput.FAILSAFE = False

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    print(arduinoData)
```

The above code changes the data into string but I want the data in integer form.

I tried to convert it into integer using this code

```
data = int.from_bytes(arduinoData, byteorder='big')
```

but this gave me something that I cannot use
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066
3149066

I want this in this form:
2
3
4
5
5
6
6
7
7
8
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
16

The above is the string value and I want the exact value as an integer I cannot figure out how to do it please help me.

Comment: The language is python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `int()` instead of `int.from_bytes()`:

```
import serial
import pydirectinput

pydirectinput.FAILSAFE = False

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=115200, timeout=1)

while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
    data = int(arduinoData)
    print(data)
```

`int.from_bytes()` expects binary data. If you decode the data first with `.decode()` and then try to decode it again with `from_bytes()`, the result will be incorrect.